# Entity Framework Can we dynamically change schema?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Lets say I have a database with Car.Prices, Car.PaintPrices, Motorcicle.Prices and Motorcicle.PaintPrices with the same structure ID and Price.

Is it possible to have a method `GiveTotalPrice(int veicleId, int paintId, string schema)` that depending on the schema reads the correct tables? (the tables and structure are the same, just the schema changed).

How would I make that if (its possible)?

*edit*:
Maybe have 2 dbContexts could work, can they coexist in the same project? (I'm wondering how a database-update would work?)

Comment: Viva ADO.Net!!!

Comment: I guess, it has nothing to do with the DB schema. Just check the type of the vehicle and make a relevant call in your C# code.

Comment: @VladimirSerykh yes I could, the idea would be to be capable of add new vehicle types and have minimal changes to the code. I think maybe creating different DBcontexts might work, but I would rather not.

Comment: @RagnaRock but how would adding different DbContexts not require changes to the code? Column `Type` in table `Vehicles` could just be an `int` which refers to another table `VehicleTypes` in which you can just insert a new row with no code changes at all.

Comment: @Xerillio I was thinking on having the same entity type (just vehicle) for both dbcontexts. Still not sure if it is possible... I was just wondering if there could be an elegant solution for this kind of problem. (And this is just a simplification of my actual problem, my actual problem I have a sales model that I process to generate some forecasts and multiple sales sources depending on the type of product sold, but all of them can use the same sales processing method).

Comment: @RagnaRock if a solution using a simple "type column" in the table doesn't work for you, I think you need to update the question with an example that fits better with your actual problem. At the moment it seems like the solution is to just structure your data more appropriately.